# User-Specific Value for Object in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am an absolute novice at using ASP.NET MVC3, and I'm having a great deal of trouble figuring out how to do something that is probably very easy.

Here's my public class:

```
public class Proposal
{
    ProposalDBEntities proposalDB = 
        new ProposalDBEntities();
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Target_Finish_Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Estimated_Cost { get; set; }
    public int Staffing { get; set; }
    public decimal Maintenance { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_Added { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public decimal VoteAverage { get; set; }
}
```

I simply want an individual logged-in user to be able to set the value for public int Rating.  That is, if the user sets it to 37, he'll see the value 37 when he logs in.  But another user who sets it to 50 will see 50.  In other words, the value for Rating will be different depending on who's logged in.  This seems like it wouldn't be hard at all, but I have no idea where to begin.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To display the rating: In your view, you would have something like `@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Rating)`. This is RAZOR syntax.  If you are using ASPX, it would be `<%: @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Rating)` %>

To have users able to edit the rating (in Entity Framework): How will your user input the rating? Personally, as a beginner, you can create an Entity Data Model and generate code based on your database structure. Then, you can create a controller with CRUD (create, read, update, delete) principles that gives the user the ability to edit his/her rating (Keep in mind that there are views created in addition to edit: create, delete, details, and index. Use what is relevant to you.)

Lots of info to digest, I'm sure. Feel free to ask me anything. I'm in your shoes as well. Hope this helps.